# Wordpress - IIS 7.5 - URL rewrite - OWA and RWW 403.18 Forbidden

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This rule is located in my wwwroot folder, it fixes my URL's, but it breaks my OWA and RWW websites.

How can I add an exception, or condition, to this rule so that it ignores a particular address? I am trying to process the domain name **remote.mydomain.com**, normally.

With the rule above in place, **remote.mydomain.com**, will return a 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a condition to your rule:

```
<rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^remote\.mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

the condition

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^remote\.mydomain\.com$" negate="true" />`
```

will prevent your rule from trigger if the requested host is exactly `remote.mydomain.com`

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer and help explain why and how the condition works. Keep up the great work and thanks again!